# Assembly.LoadFile cannot find the file at the design time

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

My resource files are in another project. In App.xaml.cs in MainwindowProject, I write code as below to load the resource file.

```
static ResourceBundle CreateResourceBundle()
        {

             string dllPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Trade.Resources.dll";
               ResourceBundle resBundle = new ResourceBundle(Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath));
                resBundle.LocaleRoot = "Trade.Resources.locale"; //where my locale files are
                resBundle.AddResourceFile("Resources");

                string culture = "en-US";
                resBundle.Locale = culture;
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
               return resBundle;
}
```

some usercontrols are using this resBundle. It's working fine at the run time. But, If I Open the parent xaml window at design time, I got this exception and usercontrol cannot be loaded.

```
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
```

How could i solve this? Thanks.

Edit : Temporary workaround

I just added the interface in Trade.Resources project.  And in App.xaml.cs , it's as below.

```
Type iResType = Type.GetType("Trade.Resources.IRes,Trade.Resources", true);
            ResourceBundle resBundle = new ResourceBundle(Assembly.GetAssembly(iResType));
```

so far, it's working fine at both design time and run time.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "Copy to Output Directory" property of Resource files to Copy Always. By doing this your resource file will be copied to the Bin directory of the executing assembly. Even if this doesn't work, make your Resource an embedded resource and try reading it from manifest

Comment: still not working. For temporary work around, I just add Interface in resource solution. Then, I create this type in app.xaml.cs and use "Assembly.GetAssembly(iResType)". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are fetching file, once you set the Copy to Output Directory" property of Resource files to Copy Always, then just load the file, it should work

Comment: I've already tried your suggestion. I still got FileNotFound Excpetion. Thanks.